# How to check authenticated status server side with ionic cloud Auth

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cloud

I'm evaluating whether to use Ionic's cloud [Auth](https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/#emailpassword-authentication) service and it seems like it's relatively easy to implement client-side, where you can check `this.auth.isAuthenticated`.  You can also set the user info from the client side as well.

However, if I want to do check their identity server-side, such as check that a user is authenticated when they call my custom api to post a comment - how can I get some sort of token (preferably a JWT token) that I can use to validate their identity server-side?  Assuming we are using email/password authentication.

Also - using their send notification on a user's birthday example, how can I query the user data in ionic cloud's database to say find all users who have a birthday today.  Can I export out the user data in any way if I want to migrate away in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a JWT authentication service server side.
In other words when the user is authenticated, the app can send a JWT token to the server which should be evaluated to trust the remote user.
For more info reads: https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/custom-auth.html
A php example here: https://github.com/driftyco/custom-auth-examples/tree/master/php

Regards from Italy

Comment: What if I don't want to use Ionic cloud? any workaround?